# What does the question mark icon by a file name mean in Aptana?

Tags: git, github, aptana, aptana3

I copied a Three.js script from one project into another and now there's a small question mark in a white box next to the icon of the copied file. What does this mean? Thanks for your help!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved! It seems that the boxed question mark icon indicates a new, untracked file in a local git repository, as I had not yet begun tracking this file when I took the screenshot above. After I added it to the next commit/push the question mark box went away.